# Why was this question (about Hogwart lessons) reopened?

Tags: discussion

The question

[What is the maximum number of O.W.L. classes you can take at Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/136071/how-many-classes-can-you-take-without-a-time-turner)

Seems to be almost entirely a duplicate of

[How did Bill and Percy get 12 OWLs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72839/how-did-bill-and-percy-get-12-owls)

Which is why I closed it as a dupe. **So why has it been reopened?**

Comment: Because the answer may not be 12... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/138381/57310

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/does-this-meta-policy-overrule-our-meta/9748#9748 shogs answer leaves us with a little wiggle room if we want it

Comment: @Himarm - I've made it less dupey by editing. I think I was probably thrown by the wording

Answer (score 9):

The questions are similar but they are not duplicates.

The first (older) question focuses specifically on how *two specific students* managed to take *a specific number* of classes in a semester, and if they did or did not need time turner help to do so.

The second question starts with the premise that you have no special magical help; what is the *maximum* number of classes you could take. It's possible that the answers are the same: that Bill and Percy took as many as possible. But it may be different. The class schedule may allow more, or it may be that it's not even possible to take 12 and they had to use magical help.

There is a lot of overlap, but far less than other questions that have been judged not-duplicates, given that the answers *may or may not* be the same.

Comment: "*since we (I believe) have stopped dupe-closing questions based entirely on their answers"* - Huh? When did we decide that?

Comment: I must have been thinking about something else, because I can't find anything newer than [June](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/does-this-meta-policy-overrule-our-meta) and it doesn't say what I thought it did.

Comment: Nope. The consensus then was a continuation of the existing consensus that similar answers provoke dupe-close.

Comment: It also says: " But this doesn't hold if a question has managed to attract a lot of different answers ".. .the duplicate you linked two had two very different, contradictory, answers, and one of them explicitly claimed "they had time turners" which is of no help to the new question. I think the dupe-ness is fuzzy enough to leave them both open, though a link to the original in comment would be very helpful.

Comment: I would also suggest that if you have a chat in chat about group-reversing the dupehammer decision of a gold tag badge holder, it might be polite to put a comment explaining why and link to said chat.

Comment: so I was apparently confusing two duplicate-questions discussions going on in parallel. The chat conversation was about an *Under the Dome* question; this one I VTRO based on my comments to [this answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10078/2816), where I suggested that it wasn't really a dupe. I dunno where the other VTROs came from.

Comment: Hmm. As written it was very dupey. I've made it more obvious what the OP was driving at.